# Pyspark, joins ,sql,outer join

Tags: python, sql, join, pyspark, outer-join

I have a requirement like this...I wanted to outer join two tables A and B(for example) so that if the key matches my output should have the values of table B(not A column values)
Ex

```
A
a b
1 abc
2 fgh
3 xyz

B
a b
1 wer
6 uio
```

output

```
a b
1 wer
2 fgh
3 xyz
6 uio
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
We also expect a clear problem specification.

Answer (score 0):

This is a prioritization query.  You seem to want all rows from `b` and then the non-matching rows from `a` based on the first column.

One method is `union all`:

```
select b.*
from b
union all
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.a = a.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

A Pyspark solution would be to use a `full` join and `coalesce`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Create dataframes
A = spark.createDataFrame(data=[[1, 'abc'], [2, 'fgh'], [3, 'xyz']], schema=['a', 'b'])
B = spark.createDataFrame(data=[[1, 'wer'], [6, 'uio']], schema=['a', 'b'])

# Rename column `b` to prevent naming collision 
A = A.select('a', F.col('b').alias('b_a'))
B = B.select('a', F.col('b').alias('b_b'))

# Full join on `a` keeps all entries from both dataframes
combined = A.join(B, on='a', how='full')

# Coalesce takes value from `b_b` if not null and `b_a` otherwise
combined = combined.withColumn('b', F.coalesce('b_b', 'b_a'))

# Drop unneeded helper columns
combined = combined.drop('b_b', 'b_a')

combined.show()
```

**Result**

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|wer|
|  2|fgh|
|  3|xyz|
|  6|uio|
+---+---+
```